# specify the docker file name with `-f Dockerfile` yields error when building image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile (There is no problem with this Dockerfile itself, it is provided by a 3rd party).

The directory structure:

```
webapp/
   - Dockfile
   - app.py
```

I can build the image by: `docker build .` It successfully built a image with no image name nor tag:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                          <none>              ee49229fe570        44 seconds ago      913MB
```

I would like to build the image with a name (repository) called "webapp-color" without tag. So, I re-build the image by `docker build -f Dockerfile -t webapp-color`, but this command gives error:

```
$ docker build -f Dockerfile -t webapp-color
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.
```

Then, I changed a little bit the command, by executing `docker build . -t webapp-color`, now it successed.

Why I can't specify `-f Dockerfile`? I understand it is the default docker file name docker looks for but I don't understand why I can't explictly specify it.

I checked my docker version:

```
Docker version 19.03.15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was not about having a `-f Dockerfile`, but rather about not having that PATH (`.`) to the context at the end. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with-path) for more details.

> This example specifies that the `PATH` is `.`, and so all the files in the local directory get `tar`d and sent to the Docker daemon. The PATH specifies where to find the files for the “context” of the build on the Docker daemon. Remember that the daemon could be running on a remote machine and that no parsing of the Dockerfile happens at the client side (where you’re running `docker build`). That means that all the files at `PATH` get sent, not just the ones listed to ADD in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean something like `docker build . -f Dockerfile -t webapp-color` in my case?

Comment: sure, that should do it

Comment: I usualy do
```docker build -f mydockerfile -t mytag .```